# Ocaml Cmliner how to choose between two possible sets of arguments

Tags: ocaml

The question is about arguments in Cmdliner. (I just expect some examples in the following problem, I will do the rest)
I need an example cmdliner's use: Let's assume we want CLI program that able to add a man's name to list and then randomly get N persons from the list.

So the first case is:

```
./prog user add Peter
Ok!
```

case number two:

```
./prog user get 3
Max
Peter
Ann
```

I wrote the programme partly:

```
let user_cmd = ??? (*need help with arguments here*)
let default_cmd =
  Term.(ret (const ())),
  Term.info "ompdc" 
let cmds : ('a Term.t * Term.info) list = [user_cmd]
let prog = Term.(exit @@ eval_choice default_cmd cmds)
```

How to define user_cmd?

Answer (score 0):

The [cmdliner documentation](https://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner) includes a few examples and I would recommend to go through them in order to truly master cmdliner (which indeed could be hard to grok from the first time). I've created a minimal example for your case, from which you can build your application (of course this is a toy example and for its real work we need some persistence, but it is out of the scope)

```
open Cmdliner
open Printf

(* the application logic *)

let db = ref [||]

let add_person name =
  db := Array.append !db [|name |];
  printf "%s registration number is %04d\n" name (Array.length !db - 1)

let get_person pos =
  if pos < Array.length !db
  then print_endline !db.(pos)
  else printf "unknown registration number\n"

(* the command-line interface *)

let add_person_cmd =
  let person_name =
    Arg.(required & pos 0 (some string) None & info []) in
  let doc = "Add the specified person to the database." in
  Term.(const add_person $ person_name),
  Term.info "add" ~doc

let get_person_cmd =
  let person_number =
    Arg.(required & pos 0 (some int) None & info []) in
  let doc = "Retrieves a person from the database by its regnumber" in
  Term.(const get_person $ person_number),
  Term.info "get" ~doc

(* the default command just prints the man page *)
let default_cmd =
  let doc = "A database of names" in
  Term.(ret (const (`Help (`Pager, None)))),
  Term.info "ompdc" ~doc

let cmds = [
  add_person_cmd;
  get_person_cmd;
]

let () = Term.(exit @@ eval_choice default_cmd cmds)
```

To build, put this code in a file (e.g., `example.ml`) and then use the following command

```
 ocamlbuild example.native
```

Alternatively, use [the Dune build system](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick-start.html).